# How to convert InputStream.read() to double?

Tags: java

Is there a simple way to convert arrays of bytes read from stream to a double values?

```
InputStream input = serialPort.getInputStream();
while(true) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[ 8 ];
  len = input.read( buffer );
}
```

buffer => double ?

Can you explain me figuratively how InputStream.read(byte[] b) works?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to wrap that InputStream into another Stream that's easier to use? Perhaps a DataInputStream that's wrapped by a BufferedInputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do such operations a lot, maybe it is better to use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), which provides a set of operations, like readDouble and so on.

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(serialPort.getInputStream());
double d = input.readDouble();
```

Answer (score 2):

`InputStream.read(byte[] b)` will read the next bytes into `b` argument.

And, you can try using [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read Double, Float, Integer, and others. You can instantiate a DataInputStream using:

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(YOUR_INPUT_STREAM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your InputStream object with DataInputStream ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)) and use readDouble method